# Regarding inbuilt application PostGreSQL

Tags: package-management, postgresql

In my work I need to study about FOSSology. This tool supports only in Linux. So i have installed Ubuntu version 12.10 Quantal. Through net i have come to know Ubuntu has inbuilt postgreSQL application. But when i installed i don't know how to see whether it is already installed. Could you please help me in solving this issue. It's high priority and i have short time to finish my work.

I have downloaded manually and while install after executing this command sudo dpkg -i File.dep i am getting error message saying that This need root user privileges.
PLease help me.

Answer (score 2):

The following command when run from the terminal will tell you:

```
dpkg -l postgresql
```

If it shows:

```
No packages found matching postgresql.
```

this means it isn't installed. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

It will ask you for your password and then download, install and configure postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to install, you need root privileges. However, you should use the built-in `apt`. Run:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

If it is already installed, it will tell you and gracefully fail. When it finishes, or says it is already installed, you have PostgreSQL.

If you *really* need to use the existing .deb file(this is ***not recommended***), use:

```
sudo dpkg -i file.deb
```